# How to require assets only for development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets, asset-pipeline

I'm using the assets pipeline from Rails 3.1 and I want to include some javascript files only if it's the development environment.

Example:

```
//= require application/jquery
//= require application/jquery_ujs
// next ones only for development environment
//= require application/badglobals
//= require application/consul
```

Its there a standar way of doing this? Any suggestions?

**Update**

Looking at the Sprockets current documentation, seems like there is not a way to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just require these in the view? Is it important that they are loaded in the asset? To load them in the view:

```
<% if Rails.env.development? %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application/badglobals" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application/consul" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You're right, since I want it only for development really don't need the assets pipeline here.

Comment: My first question, a bad one... anyway thanks for the answer. Subscribed to your blog!

Comment: @mooddha: Not a bad one at all! It was clear what you were trying to do, you just weren't doing it in the right way. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

If you rename your `application.js` file (or whichever file you're calling `//= require ...` in) to `application.js.erb`, you can take advantage of `require_asset`. i.e:

```
//= require application/jquery
//= require application/jquery_ujs
<% if Rails.env.development? %>
  <%= require_asset 'application/badglobals' %>
  <%= require_asset 'application/consul' %>
<% end %>
```

Source: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/90

Comment: Cleanest way to do it.